# How to return a value of an async function call inside a filter function

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angular-translate

I am trying to implement a filter to convert the month in integer format into a month string (e.g. 1 into January). The result should be translated into the selected language with angular-translate. `MONTH_X` are the identifiers in my language json file.

The problem is, that the `$transclate` function is async and I don't know how to return a value from an async function inside a filter.

This does not work:

```
app.filter('monthName', ['$translate', function($translate) {
    return function (monthNumber) { //1 = January
        var monthNames = [ 'MONTH_1', 'MONTH_2', 'MONTH_3', 'MONTH_4', 'MONTH_5', 'MONTH_6',
            'MONTH_7', 'MONTH_8', 'MONTH_9', 'MONTH_10', 'MONTH_11', 'MONTH_12' ];

        return $translate(monthNames[monthNumber - 1]).then(function (month) {
            return month;
        });
    }
}]);
```

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: You are aware that `$translate.instant` exists...!?

Comment: @Dennis can you show error please?

Comment: I dont't get any error. The filter returns only an empty String. If I add an alert(month) inside the $traslate.then(..) callback function a see the correct translated month string.

Comment: Why do you not use date filter ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: You can't use datefilter to convert mont_int to month_name (1 -> january). I have not a complete date object, only the month int value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of translated months when creating the filter. Filters are meant to be fast that is why there is no support for promises.

Example:

```
app.filter('monthName', ['$translate', function($translate) {

    var monthNames = [ 'MONTH_1', 'MONTH_2', 'MONTH_3', 'MONTH_4', 'MONTH_5', 'MONTH_6',
            'MONTH_7', 'MONTH_8', 'MONTH_9', 'MONTH_10', 'MONTH_11', 'MONTH_12' ];
    var translatedMonths = [];

    monthNames.forEach(function(month) {
        $translate(month).then(function (translatedMonth) {
            translatedMonths.push(translatedMonth);
        });
    });

    return function (monthNumber) { //1 = January
        return translatedMonths[monthNumber - 1];
    }
}]);
```

Other option would be to use *$translate.instant* method if you can.

Example:

```
app.filter('monthName', ['$translate', function($translate) {
    return function (monthNumber) { //1 = January
      var monthNames = [ 'MONTH_1', 'MONTH_2', 'MONTH_3', 'MONTH_4', 'MONTH_5', 'MONTH_6',
            'MONTH_7', 'MONTH_8', 'MONTH_9', 'MONTH_10', 'MONTH_11', 'MONTH_12' ];

      return $translate.instant(monthNames[monthNumber - 1]);
    }
}]);
```